# Associating a vb Object to a specific worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with VB in Excel (Office 2010).

I have a class called Problem and a vb code that generates random problems and for each problem creates a new worksheet and prints the parameters of the problem to that worksheet.

when I work on that worksheet, I need some of the parameters that are stored in the instance of the Problem object that generated the worksheet and change them dynamically.

what I would like to do is associate an instance of the Problem to its worksheet
something like:

```
 Dim p as Problem 

 Set p = new Problem 

 Worksheet("Problem 1").**myCurrentProblem** = p
```

and then later on have access to the variable `myCurrentProblem`

is there a way to do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe do it the other way around... In your `Problem` class, store a worksheet variable, maybe?

Comment: Are you referring to the *class properties* for the object?

Comment: I have a function that takes a Problem instance and some more numbers that I want it to take from the worksheet and compute something.
something like this:

=myFunction(this_problem_instance,E5,D7) 

but I can't access the instance of the problem because I don't know which one it is.

I could by pass it by holding a global collection of problems and worksheets but I'd prefer if It would be associated to the worksheet

Comment: You can't assign arbitrary properties to a worksheet object, but you could define a `currentProblem` field in the sheet's code module and assign your object to that.  You'd have to do that for each sheet though. A global collection would be easier to manage, since it wouldn't require code in the sheet modules.

Comment: @TimWilliams you could assign these arbitrary properties (as long as they are string-able) to the worksheet's `CustomXMLPart`.  It's a PITA, but it's certainly possible to do so :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - good point: that's something I've not yet really dealt with.

Comment: @TimWilliams me neither, although I'm about to get buck wild with CustomXMLParts in PowerPoint in the next few weeks. Migrating metadata from a document-level container to individual shapes/charts/etc. for automation purposes. I've only briefly tested some stuff, but it could be pretty powerful in the right hands :)

Answer (score 1):

Or what about having a class e.g **ProblemSheet** which will **bind sheet and problem instances**? Those instances will be stored in a **collection of ProblemSheets**. Example (a little bit too long example but HTH).

> **ThisWorkbook class code:**

```
Private m_problemSheets As Collection

Public Sub AddProblemSheet(problemSheetParameter As ProblemSheet)
    If m_problemSheets Is Nothing Then _
        Set m_problemSheets = New Collection
    m_problemSheets.Add problemSheetParameter, problemSheetParameter.SheetInstance.Name
End Sub

Public Function ProblemOfSheet(sheetName As String) As ProblemSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ProblemOfSheet = m_problemSheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set m_problemSheets = New Collection
End Sub
```

> **Problem class module: (just for testing purposes)**

```
Public Name As String
```

> **ProblemSheet class module:**

```
Private m_problem As Problem
Private m_sheet As Worksheet

Public Sub Bind(problemParametr As Problem, sheetParameter As Worksheet)
    Set m_problem = problemParametr
    Set m_sheet = sheetParameter
End Sub

Public Property Get ProblemInstance() As Problem
    Set ProblemInstance = m_problem
End Property

Public Property Set ProblemInstance(newProblem As Problem)
    Set m_problem = newProblem
End Property

Public Property Get SheetInstance() As Worksheet
    Set SheetInstance = m_sheet
End Property
```

> **Standard module code:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newProblem As Problem
    Dim newProblemSheet As ProblemSheet



    ' add data to collection first
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Set newProblem = New Problem
        newProblem.Name = "Problem_" & i

        Set newProblemSheet = New ProblemSheet
        newProblemSheet.Bind newProblem, Worksheets(i)

        ThisWorkbook.AddProblemSheet newProblemSheet
    Next


    ' get problem from collection by sheet name
    Dim ps As ProblemSheet
    Set ps = ThisWorkbook.ProblemOfSheet(Worksheets("Problem 1").Name)

    If Not ps Is Nothing Then _
        Debug.Print ps.ProblemInstance.Name



    ' set problem instance to another problem :-)
    Dim myCurrentProblem As Problem

    Set myCurrentProblem = New Problem
    myCurrentProblem.Name = "myCurrentProblem 1"
    Set ThisWorkbook.ProblemOfSheet(Worksheets("Problem 1").Name).ProblemInstance = myCurrentProblem

    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.ProblemOfSheet(Worksheets("Problem 1").Name).ProblemInstance.Name
End Sub
```